# Trouble connecting GNU emacs to work machine through SSH & TRAMP

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, ssh

I am a new emacs user. Previously, for work, I would ssh into my work machine by activating my VPN and then running `ssh work` (`work` is an ssh nickname defined in `.ssh/config`) in my terminal. This would bring me to my virtual machine. From here I would fire up my configured vim-tmux setup.

I am now converting to emacs (specifically spacemacs), but I can't seem to connect to my virtual machine with emacs GNU. I have tried two methods of connecting with TRAMP

1. I run helm-find-files (SPC f f) and type `/ssh:work:`
2. open an eshell and type /ssh:work:`

In both cases, emacs GNU freezes up and says `Waiting for prompts from remote shell...` for quite some time. Then a mini buffer pops up resembling the azure virtual machine I work on. However, any button press immediately closes the mini buffer. Then the bottom says `/ssh:work:/: command not found`

I have tried to the best of my ability to read the docs to figure out what I need to do, but I quickly get overwhelmed by the scope of TRAMP. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you have trouble with the remote shell prompt. This needs debugging. Since this is out of the sx scope, I recommend to contact the Tramp mailing list. See the Tramp manual for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I routinely use multi-hop nicknames with ssh and tramp and it works just fine. As @MichaelAlbinus said, `tramp` is probably getting hung up on your prompt. It doesn't like all the cool features we cram in to our prompts now-a-days. The trick is to dumb your shell down when using `tramp`. I'm a `zsh` user, so early in my shell init (at the top of my `~/.zshrc`) I have the following:

```bsh
## tramp gets hung up on precmd(), unset some features
if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
   unsetopt zle
   unsetopt prompt_cr
   unsetopt prompt_subst
   unfunction precmd
   unfunction preexec
   PS1='$ '
   return
fi
```

In `bash` you can probably get away with just

```bsh
if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
   PS1='$ '
   return
fi
```

at the top of your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Seems sensible, although I always thought that tramp explicitly used `/bin/sh` (or at least the default `tramp-methods` does not define any remote shell value other than that).  Surely you don't have `zsh` at `/bin/sh` ?

Comment: This worked great. To clarify, I added the bash code snippet to the remote terminal -- not the local. (Probably obvious but I wasn't totally sure at first)

Comment: I should have clarified! My shell init stuff is in version control so it’s all then same to me ;)